# Sending email with java mail api

Tags: java, android, email

i m developing an app in which i must send an email using the java mail api i added the jar files and the internet permission in the manifest but i didn't recieved anything and this is how i code it

```
 try {
                            GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("user@gmail.com", "testpass");
                            sender.sendMail("This is Subject",
                                    "This is Body",
                                    "user@gmail.com",
                                    "fatma@yahoo.com");
                            System.out.println("maiiiiiiiiiil here ");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
                        }
                        loginActicity.startActivity(i);

                    }
```

and this is the gmailsender class

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
private String user;
private String password;
private Session session;

static {
    Security.addProvider(new com.test.appsocle.JSSEProvider());
}

public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
}

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
    try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setDataHandler(handler);
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        else
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
        Transport.send(message);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
    private byte[] data;
    private String type;

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        if (type == null)
            return "application/octet-stream";
        else
            return type;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");
    }
}
```

}
and this is JSSEProvider class

public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

```
public JSSEProvider() {
    super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
        public Void run() {
            put("SSLContext.TLS",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
            put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
            put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
            put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Is there any error in the stacktrace?

Comment: no error in the logcat

Comment: You have empty `catch` blocks, specially in the `sendMail` method. Log the execeptions there.

Comment: catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
                            }
 but nothing